# Python: How to concatenate all possible combinations in two lists?

Tags: python, concatenation

```
list1=['A','B']

list2=[1,2,3]
```

How do I make it so the output shows all possible combinations in this order and without any brackets?

```
A1

A2

A3

B1

B2

B3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
list1 = ['A', 'B']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
for e1,e2 in product(list1, list2):
    print(e1+str(e2))
```

Output:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
list3 = [a+b for a in list1 for b in map(str, list2)]
print(*list3, sep = "\n") 
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        print(i+str(j))
```